# Sharing state between Targets

Tags: c#, nuke-build

Is it possible to share state between `Targets` in Nuke?

Lets say I wanted this scenerario.

```
class Build : NukeBuild {
    public static int Main () => Execute<Build>(x => x.Clean);

    Target Clean => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            string stateToRestore = "I am needed in Restore Target"; 
        });

    Target Restore => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Clean)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stateToRestore);
        });
}
```

I know it is possible to either create a property, field or some object holding the state in the scope of `Build` class. I am looking for an builtin solution in `Nuke` or a "cleaner" solution whatever that means.